# Target elements without *any* attributes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a selector method that allows policing whether, eg. the HTML tag is a clean "<html>" with no attributes whatsoever?

I'm trying to create a Stylish override sheet for browser-generated image pages in Firefox, but I essentially have to apply it to all URIs since such pages are always still ostensibly from the images' own domains.

The easiest way seems to be testing whether the HTML and Body tags have *zero* attributes (plus only-child and class selection on the image tag) because the structure of most documents which haven't been generated by the browser won't start as simply as `<html><body><img class="...`

But all I can find is how to exclude a specific attribute, not *all* of them.

I've tried the following with no success:

```css
[] {
  color: blue;
}

[*] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Clean element with no attributes</p>
<p class="has-class">Has class attribute</p>
<p id="has-id">Has ID attribute</p>
<p data-has-data-attribute="">Has data attribute</p>
```

The only remaining option I can come up with is just policing the standard attributes one would see ("class", "style", "name", "lang", etc.), but that's a lengthy and ever-changing list, notwithstanding the numerous non-standard ones.

Comment: You seem to be talking about CSS properties and HTML attributes interchangably

Comment: From what I see in [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), the attribute name in CSS attribute selector needs explicitly clarification, so I guess no luck here.

Comment: What's a "browser-generated image page"?

Comment: Firefox loads image URIs as a minimally structured valid HTML document, presumably so things like accessibility and styling add-ons will still function as intended.

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken when I used "properties" when I meant "attributes"; I've changed it. Perhaps that's why I wasn't finding the information for which I was looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A selector that matches a tag without attributes doesn't currently exist.

I read through [the latest CSS selector reference](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/) and couldn't find a selector that does what you wish.

You can't use an asterisk in the attribute selector to select everything unfortunately. These two railroad diagrams represent what is allowed:

[image: Railroad diagram of what text is allowed in the attribute selector]

[image: Railroad diagram of what string is allowed in the attribute selector]

So your first two attempts are invalid, and the valid empty string seems to have no effect:

```css
[] {
  color: blue;
}

[*] {
  color: red;
}

[""] { /* Seems to select nothing, rather than 'no attribute' */
  color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<p>Clean element with no attributes</p>
<p class="has-class">Has class attribute</p>
<p id="has-id">Has ID attribute</p>
<p data-has-data-attribute="">Has data attribute</p>
```

I can't come up with any possible hack that doesn't involve JavaScript. I will edit this answer if I figure out a solution.